# How to setup PostGIS with an existing database?

Tags: django, postgresql, postgis

I have a database which has one table, Schools. This table also has latitude and longitude columns as 'float' type. I have installed PostGIS. I have created a postgis database using template_postgis_20. I, then added a table with datatype geometry. Now, how do I transfer latitude and longitude to this table from another Schools table?

I am using this for a Django application. I need to make queries like find schools within 5 miles of a student's current location( latitude and longitude).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you installed correctly postgis in your database, with the geometric functions I suggest you install and use [south](http://south.aeracode.org) for that migration, first read the [tutorial](http://south.aeracode.org/docs/tutorial/index.html) and then make a [data migration](http://south.aeracode.org/docs/tutorial/part3.html#data-migrations)

Comment: Hi, I am not sure how to go about enabling my database with postgis?

Comment: You need to follow the installation tutorial here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/install/#ref-gis-install